# About regex case

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a url from html code using regular expressiones. I don't know too much about regex, so I'm a bit confused because it is not working. This is the case:

```
<a href="cotizacion-valor/abengoa/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#006699;">ABG.MC</a>
```

And I'm trying to get "abengoa" using this regex:

```
".*cotizacion-valor\/(/w+)\/.*"
```

Also, I'm using python, so the code is:

```
regex_companies = ".*cotizacion-valor\/(/w+)\/.*"
match_companies = re.findall(regex_companies, content_web)
```

What is bad with my regex? Thanks

EDIT: One more question:

What can I do to get only the first match? Because this href is repeating along the document with the same content (but also with different, so I have to search all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `/w` is incorrect. You have to use `\w` instead of `/w`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` pattern matches any number of any characters (greedy). Use non-greedy version `.*?` which will match as-much-as-it-can instead. Also it's `\w` not `/w`:

```
`.*?cotizacion-valor\/(\w+)\/.*?`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rex = ".*cotizacion-valor\/(?P<param_name>.*?)\/.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=.*cotizacion-valor/)(\w+)(?=\/.*)`

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
<a\s+href=\"(?<yourUrl>[^\"])\"
```

and get group named *yourUrl*